# Capturing stderr using py.tests capsys

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to use [py.tests `capsys` fixture](http://pytest.org/latest/capture.html?highlight=capsys#accessing-captured-output-from-a-test-function) to capture the standard error stream. However, this doesn't seem to work as advertised. Given this simple test:

```
from sys import stderr


def test_capsys(capsys):
    print('foo')
    print('bar', file=stderr)

    out, err = capsys.readouterr()
    assert out == 'foo\n'
    assert err == 'bar\n'
```

Produces the following output when run with py.test 2.7.0 on Python 3.4.3:

```
    def test_capsys(capsys):
        print('foo')
        print('bar', file=stderr)

        out, err = capsys.readouterr()
        assert out == 'foo\n'
>       assert err == 'bar\n'
E       assert '' == 'bar\n'
E         + bar

test_capsys.py:10: AssertionError
----------------------------- Captured stderr call -----------------------------
bar
```

The strange thing is that py.test reports the correct contents for the error stream, but `capsys` doesn't seem to capture it. Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 7):

The `capsys` fixture works by replacing `sys.stderr` with it's own virtual file object. In the code given above, this replacement happens only *after*  the test imports `sys.stderr`, making it useless. To fix this problem, one can import `sys.stderr` inside the test.

```
def test_capsys(capsys):
    from sys import stderr

    print('foo')
    print('bar', file=stderr)

    out, err = capsys.readouterr()
    assert out == 'foo\n'
    assert err == 'bar\n'
```

This problem is better described in the [documentation of the `unittest.mock` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html?highlight=mock#where-to-patch).

Comment: Just to add to the answer, and alternative would be to `import sys` and use `sys.stderr` in your code.